# not able to add flutter to my path variable. I am using ohmyzsh on mac OS catalina

Tags: flutter

I have added the line: `export PATH=~/Users/aryanchordia/flutter/bin:$PATH`

to my .zshrc file and when i type `which flutter` it says flutter command not found

Answer (score 1):

solved.

changed PATH variable to `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/aryanchordia/flutter/bin"`